# R Extract 6 digits from string

Tags: r, regex

How can I extract **only six digit numbers** in a string using R. I tried the  following code. However, it returns the first digits encountered

> as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\1", x))

Example

> 56 NE. Vale Ave. Fullerton, CA 928311

The result should be

> 982311

- The digits **DO NOT** always appear at the end of the string and
  could be placed anywhere in the string.
- Multiple numbers can appear in the string. However, I'm fairly confident that there's only one six-digit number in it.

Comment: You might want to check your data.  US zip codes are 5 digits.

Comment: @RichScriven Using dummy data for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
as.numeric(sub(".*([0-9]{6})$", "\\1", str1))
#[1] 928311
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "56 NE. Vale Ave. Fullerton, CA 928311"
```